# JDBC connection hard code, not using glassfish connection pool

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, ejb

I have a question about the database connection for JPA layer in Glassfish,well, not actually in Glassfish.

I have seen a project using EJB+JPA+Glassfish, however, for the JPA level, the connection to Oracle database is not configured in Glassfish connection pool. It is hard code in JPA level code with JDBC.

I just wondering, will this cause any problems when volumn testing. Will this cause a problem on concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

The only "problem" is the DB access is not managed and configured by the server (Glassfish) but for the hard code written.